# How to know if ASCII is used?

Tags: c, character-encoding, ascii

I've done some research, but I didn't find an answer to my question. I would like to know how to determine if the used charset in a C program is ASCII. Are there any preprocessor constants ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C says:

> (C99, 5.2.1p1) "The values of the members of the execution character set       are implementation-defined."

For example `gcc` says:

> The values of the members of the execution character set (C90 and C99 5.2.1).
>   *Determined by ABI*

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Characters-implementation.html

So `gcc` points to the operating system documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, the ASCII charsets are range from 0 - 127, and other charsets are below zero.

Comment: UTF-8 is not strictly 'below zero'. Any ASCII is also valid UTF-8.

Comment: And `char` can be unsigned, in which case the other characters are above 127, not below zero. And in principle a C implementation needed use ASCII for the values 0-127, for example there have been implementations that use EBCDIC instead.

Answer (score 1):

It depend on toolchain that you are using, you may find it in toolchain document. For example, vc++ define _UNICODE for unicode build.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to construct a preprocessor macro for that yourself. Something like the following should do the trick:

```
#define HAVE_ASCII (('\x41' == 'A') && ('\x61' == 'a') && ('\x30' == '0'))

#if !HAVE_ASCII
# error "we need ascii"
#endif
```

If you want to be extremely careful you could just list all printable ASCII in the macro, but this here should be already enough to distinguish from EBCDIC. Even easier would be if you'd just to determine if you are on an EBDIC system :)

```
#define HAVE_EBCDIC (('Z' - 'A') != 25)
```